# SAPUI5 OPA5 TypeError: sap.ui.test.matchers.Properties is not a constructor

Tags: sapui5

Im facing an Issue in OPA Testing for SAPUI5 Application.

Im trying to perform OPA Testing for a SAPUI5 View , I have created a dropdown in the View and i have writted the OPA Script for the corresponding View.

When i run the OPA Sctipt, The script which i have written is not able to select the "Item" in the Drop Down, and im getting an error by saying..
TypeError: sap.ui.test.matchers.Properties is not a constructor

Im not getting why the Applcation is not fetching sap.ui.test.matchers.Properties class

Below is the Code for the issue..

Translation.View.xml

```
<Select id="toolsDocType" width="100%" change="onToolsDocChange" forceSelection="true">
<items>
<core:Item text="--Select1--" key="X" enabled="false"/>
<core:Item text="Link" key="Link"/>
<core:Item text="Atatchment" key="attachment"/>
</items>
</Select>
```

## js File

This function will start executing the test script "fillAttachment()" function

```
opaTest("Select Attachment", function (Given, When, Then) {
            // Arrangements
            //Given.iStartMyApp();

            //Actions
            When.onTheTranslationPage.fillAttachment();

            // Assertions
            Then.onTheTranslationPage.CustNameShouldGetFilled();
        });
```

After running above code the below function will starts executing.

```
 fillAttachment : function () {
                            return this.waitFor({
                                id:"toolsDocType",
                                actions: new Press(),
                            success: function(oSelect) {
                                this.waitFor({
                                    controlType: "sap.ui.core.Item",
                                    matchers: [
                                        new sap.ui.test.matchers.Ancestor(oSelect),
                                        new sap.ui.test.matchers.Properties({ key: "link"})
                                    ],
                                    actions: new Press(),
                                    success: function() {
                                        Opa5.assert.strictEqual(oSelect.getSelectedKey(), "Link", "Selected link");
                                    },
                                    errorMessage: "Cannot select link from mySelect"
                                });
                            },
                                errorMessage: "There was no Input"
                            });
                        },
```

Im seeing the below Error..
There was no Input
Exception thrown by the testcode:'TypeError: sap.ui.test.matchers.Properties is not a constructor
TypeError: sap.ui.test.matchers.Properties is not a constructor
    at f.success (https://webidetesting4022059-w3446edba.dispatcher.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com/webapp/test/integration/pages/Translation.js?eval:240:10)
    at f.r.success (https://webidetesting4022059-w3446edba.dispatcher.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/test/Opa5.js?eval:6:2978)

Can you please help me to fix this error.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the paths in the `sap.ui.require` in order to load the JS files. Please read [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8615a0b9088645ae936dbb8bbce5d01d.html) for a example.

```
sap.ui.require([
"sap/ui/test/opaQUnit",
"sap/ui/test/actions/Press",
"sap/ui/test/matchers/Properties",
"sap/ui/test/matchers/Ancestor"
],  function (opaTest, Press, Properties, Ancestor) {
     //Your code here
});
```

Another thing is that your should provide the correct value for **key** of the `Item`.

> > matchers: [
> >                    new sap.ui.test.matchers.Ancestor(oSelect),
> >                    new sap.ui.test.matchers.Properties({ key: "**Link**"})
> >                  ],

I have tried and it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. this Solution worked for me

Comment: Can you please help me how can we select radio buttons through OPA script??

Comment: @user3496976 could you please mark this post answered and open a new post with what you have tried and some code snippet so I can furthur have a look? Thank you!